# jinja2 template char limit

Tags: jinja2

in `{{blog.content}}` I want to limit the viewer to see only 50 char at most,  how can I do that using jinja2?

After searching through their documentation I have found that `{{ s|autolink[ length[ nofollow]] }}` has a length property but it will make it auto link! Which I don't want it to be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried the python slice notation?

```
{{ blog.content[:50] }}
```

Answer (score 11):

The documentation for jinja2 says to use `{{ blog.content|truncate(50) }}`. Thats what I have been using thus far.

You can find the docs for template [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#truncate).

Comment: Read the [Jinja2 truncate() filter docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.truncate).  This filter has a "leeway" parameter, may prefer to truncate at word boundaries rather than a fixed length limit, and by default replaces the truncated portion with `'...'`.  All good for making human-readable text, such as on a Web page, but you have to use several non-intuitive options if you want to simply "truncate" after the Nth character.

Answer (score 0):

**It's works for me:**

`{{article.content|safe|truncatechars:50}}`

use `this -> truncatechars:XX <- type here`

[See DOC is here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#truncatechars)

Comment: This doc is for Django.

Comment: It also adds ellipses `'...'`